# json.org zeros are saved as strings and not as numbers

Tags: java, xml, json, org.json

i am using [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) to convert a big xml to a json string. however it seems that for the number 0 it creates a string "0", while other numbers like 5 or 2 work fine and become real numbers.

xml:

```
<w count="2" winline="5" freespins="0" jackpot="false" start="0" payout="500" supergames="0" />
```

java:

```
JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
String jsontext = json.toString();
```

resulting json:

```
"w":[{"supergames":"0","freespins":"0","winline":5,"count":2,"start":"0","jackpot":false,"payout":500}
```

is there any way to make the 0 become real 0-numbers instead of strings?

Comment: XML properties have string type. XML returns strings and JSON gets them AS IS.

Comment: @kirilloid: then, why does it work for numbers other than 0?

Comment: FWIW: i have forked the json on github and fixed the bug: https://github.com/matthiasgrumet/JSON-java

Comment: and it seems, it has now been fixed on trunk: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/XML.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug.  I looked at the source and it looks like it may throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, which basically resulting in a failed conversion to a number:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/XML.java (line 327):

```
if (initial == '0' && string.charAt(negative ? 2 : 1) == '0') {
```

Throws if string starts with "0" and is only 1 character long, i.e. if the string is "0".  The exception is caught and the conversion method basically just returns the original string ("0") again unconverted.

Not many options:

1. Report the bug and hope for speedy fix.
2. Fix it yourself for now in your own copy of the file(s).
3. If your situation can accept `0.0` in lieu of `0`, then munge the "0"'s in the XML to be "0.0"'s. (credit @bestsss)

Comment: @bestsss: yes i could, but actually i dont want to. i'd rather fix the bug.

Comment: @clamp, I'd not advise you to do so (use 0.0) and fixing is the proper way to go (I'd fix it in my own lib and move on); that's just a fix if you need to cope with the issue in production.

Comment: @bestss agreed, it may be a viable option for some future readers, even if it's not an option for @clamp in this case. But hopefully, its a non-issue period in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [snippet of code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/XML.java) that transform an XML attribute into a JSON value.

I may be wrong, but the case where the value is "0" is not handled.

```
try {
            char initial = string.charAt(0);
            boolean negative = false;
            if (initial == '-') {
                initial = string.charAt(1);
                negative = true;
            }
            if (initial == '0' && string.charAt(negative ? 2 : 1) == '0') {
                return string;
            }
            if ((initial >= '0' && initial <= '9')) {
                if (string.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
                    return Double.valueOf(string);
                } else if (string.indexOf('e') < 0 && string.indexOf('E') < 0) {
                    Long myLong = new Long(string);
                    if (myLong.longValue() == myLong.intValue()) {
                        return new Integer(myLong.intValue());
                    } else {
                        return myLong;
                    }
                }
            }
        }  catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
```

Comment: shoot - you beat me cause I walked away for a minute :-)

Comment: @Bert_F, but your comment is pinpointing the actual problem! The empty catch block is quite scary considering that douglas crockford is the author of this code...

Comment: >>considering that douglas crockford, well he also uses `getClass().getClassLoader()` in some other part of the code which will not run on an applet or webstart application.